# Understanding inheritance and different classes

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm messing around with inheritance and confused on how to do a few different things. Here is what I have:

Looking at the Account class and write a main method in a different class Bank to brief experiment with some instances of the Account class.

1. Using the Account class as a base class, write two derived classes called SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount. A SavingsAccount object, in addition to the attributes of an Account object, should have an interest variable and a method which adds interest to the account. A CheckingAccount object, in addition to the instance variables of an Account object, should have an overdraft limit variable. Ensure that you have overridden methods of the Account class as necessary in both derived classes.
2. Now create a Bank class, an object of which contains an array of Account objects. Accounts in the array could be instances of the Account class, the SavingsAccount class, or the CheckingAccount class. Create some test accounts (some of each type).
3. Write an update method in the bank class. It iterates through each account, updating it in the following ways: Savings accounts get interest added (via the method you already wrote); Checking Account get a letter sent if they are in overdraft.

```
public class Account {

    private double balance; 
    private int acctNum; 

    public Account (int num)
    { 
        balance = 0.0;
        acctNum = num; 
    } 
    public void deposit (double amt)
    { 
        if (amt >0)
            balance +=amt;
        else 
            System.out.println("Account.deposit(...): "
                    +"cannot deposit negative amount.");
    }
    public void withdraw (double amt)
    {
        if (amt>0)
            balance -=amt; 
        else 
            System.err.println("Account.withdraw(...): "
                    +"cannot withdraw negative amount.");

    }
    public double getBalance() 
    { 
        return balance; 
    }
    public double getAccountNumber()
    {
        return acctNum;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
      return "Acc " + acctNum + ": " + "balance = "+ balance;   
    }
    public final void print()
    {
           System.out.println( toString()); 
    }

}
```

Now the SavingsAccount

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account { 
    private double interest;

    public SavingsAccount(int acctNum, double interest) {
        super(acctNum);
        this.interest=interest;
    }

    public double getInterest() { 
        double x= getBalance() + getBalance()*interest;
        return x;

    // public void setInterest((interest))
    // this.interest=interest;
    }
    public void AddInterest (double interest) { 
        double x = super.getBalance() * interest; 
        super.deposit(x);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" Interest : " + interest; 
    }
}
```

CheckingAccount

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
    private double limit; 

    public CheckingAccount(int acctNum, double limit) {
        super(acctNum);
        this.limit=limit;
    }

    public double getLimit() {
        return this.limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(double limit) { 
        this.limit=limit; 
    }
    public void withdraw (double limit) { 
        if (limit <= this.limit)
            super.withdraw(limit);
        else { 
            System.out.println(" Sorry, Limit Exceeded" );
        }

    }


    public String toString() { 
        return super.toString() +"Limit :   "+limit; 
    }
}
```

Bank class

```
public class Bank {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account[] accounts = new Account[2];
        accounts[0] = new SavingsAccount(2, 0.25);
        accounts[1] = new CheckingAccount(23, 50);

        for(int i=0; i<accounts.length;i++) {
            if (accounts[0].equals(SavingsAccount)
                System.out.println(accounts[0].getInterest());
        }
    }
```

So here is my problems that I am noticing.

1. In the SavingsAccount I'm not sure how to get the setInterest() to work. I have tried changing it to a int, but then that changes the Account class. How do I get that to work properly?
2. In the bank class - the for loop I have written. Its not working, I have tried  if(accounts[i].equals so so, but does not seem to function properly. What is the correct way?

As well, I'm assuming everything is coming from my SavingsAccount class.

Comment: You have not implemented an `equals` method for `Account`, so `accounts[i].equals` shouldn't work.

Comment: Are you using `CurrentAccount` and `CheckingAccount` interchangeably?

Comment: Other than that "it does not work" is not very specific. *What* does it *do* and what do you *want* it to do. Explain that with an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35052243/edit) to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated that. I typed up the wrong. It should be CheckingAccount and SavingsAccount.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are trying to do in your for-loop you need to use [`instanceof`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) to check classes, not `equals()`.

So, for example

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[2];
accounts[0] = new SavingsAccount(2, 0.25);
accounts[1] = new CheckingAccount(23, 50);

for(int i=0; i<accounts.length;i++) {
    if (accounts[i] instanceof SavingsAccount) {
        // You must cast an Account to use any of the descendant's methods
        SavingsAccount account = (SavingsAccount) accounts[i];
        System.out.println(account.getInterest());
    } else { // it's a CheckingAccount

    } 
}
```

Other than that, StackOverflow is not a place for you to dump homework requirements, so your question is overly broad to answer in completion.